# How to change a word in a string if word in a list

Tags: string, list, replace

i want to make a chat censor

```
msg = "hello bro i saw your new pc it looks really so COoLlll"

banned_words = ["hello", "hi", "wow", "hmm", "cool"]

censor = msg.lower()

censored_message = ' '.join("***" if any(word in censor for word in banned_words) else word for word in msg.split())

print(msg)
```

İ want to get this out put: *** bro i saw your new pc it looks really so ***

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use the replace function your code will became more readable.

```
msg = "hello bro i saw your new pc it looks really so COoLlll"

banned_words = ["hello", "hi", "wow", "hmm", "cool"]

for word in banned_words:
    msg = msg.replace(word, '***')

print(msg)
```

Comment: Do you know how can i make it